# How to center a ListView in a LinearLayout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a `ListView` which has two columns and what I want is to center that `ListView` in a `Linerlayout`. Here is the layout code of the `ListView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/mylist">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the layout of the individual items of the `ListView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/prayLabel"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/prayValue"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Although my `ListView` is appearing vertically centered, but it's not appearing horizontally centered as its width is spanning the entire width of the screen. I guess as I used `wrap_content` in the `layout_width` in all the places its width should not span the entire width of the screen/layout?

Thanks

Comment: add this in your second xml `android:gravity="center"` in Linear layout

Comment: @gtumca-MAC added but it did not make any difference :(.

Answer (score 3):

I would wrap it in a `RelativeLayout` for simplicity- I struggle with this too and end up doing this on simpler layouts**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <!-- Note the 'centre in parent' tag below -->

            <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/mylist"/>

       </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

** Disclaimer: This pattern can become expensive on more complex views but a `LinearLayout` > `RelativeLayout` > `ListView` hierarchy is just fine.

Comment: Well although it did center the content within the ListView but the width of the ListView remain the same i-e spans the entire width of the layout which is what I dont want, I want the width of the ListView to be reduced to the maximum width of the rows (i-e 200 dip in my case)

Comment: Have you tried setting the ````RelativeLayout```` wrapping the ````LinearLayout```` to ````wrap_content````? I always end up going at this in a bit of a trial and error fashion. If that doesn't work then after setting the RelativeLayout to wrap_content set the list view to be ````match_parent```` i.e. match the width of the RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:weightSum` on your linear layout and then use empty views either side to center your `ListView` as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".05"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".9"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".05"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

of course you can adjust the weights, jsut make sure the `Views` are set the same so the `ListView` is centered.